# Enzyme-Mocha: how to test `img` tag has non-empty `alt` property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

How do you write a test that fails if the `alt` property of an `img` doesn't exist or is empty? It feels it should be very simple but I can't get this right.

Stateless component to test (I've simplified it, for example's sake):

```
const FeaturedProject = () => (
 <div className="feat-images">
  <img
    alt="Meaningful text"
    src="./path/to/image"
  />
 </div>
)
```

This is what I tried, but the test is not passing, although it should.

```
it('should have an img tag with src and alt properties', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<FeaturedProject />);
  const { alt, src } = wrapper.find('img').props();
  assert.equal(wrapper.find('img').length, 1);
  assert.equal(alt.length, 1);
  assert.equal(src.length, 1);
});
```

I'd be thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: Shouldn't alt.length be 15 instead of 1? I `alt` literally the string "Meaningful text"?

Comment: Good point, cheers. Is there a way to test any arbitrary string length? The `alt` content might change and it can be quite long, so I don't want to manually count every time. I would use `greaterThan`, instead of `equal` but [assert doesn't seem to support that relation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html)

Comment: If you forgot to pass `alt`, it will be undefined so you just need to assert that `alt` is defined. Note that empty string `alt` is actually good practice for decorative images.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Regarding empty `alt` strings, I can see why that's recommended in case of a logo, for example, but the case in my question is different.

Comment: I see. Then simply do `assert.ok(alt.length > 8)`? `assert.ok` pass the test if you pass in truthy values.

Comment: I'll go with that, thanks. Why `8` though? I don't want it to fail when `< 8`. I'll `assert > 0`. I'll accept your answer if you care to post one @EvanSebastian